# Crystal Report Image - Help

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm using the Crystal Reports-2008 included with VisualStudio 2008. I would like to change the image that is displayed on the report at runtime ideally by building a path to the image file and then have that image displayed on the report.

Thanks,
Sr

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a straight forward way of doing this so I wrote a blog on it

http://paul-j-power.blogspot.com/2011/01/crystal-reports-how-to-insert-logo-into.html